# How to calculate two text fields of a duplicated table in javascript using keyup event?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I want to multiply unit-price by Quantity anytime I duplicate a table row which has textbox. but it isn't working out for me. Am only able to calculate for the first row in the table. Any help please?

My codes below.

```js
var int = 1;
function myFunction() {
  var tr = '<tr>'+
   '<td class="table_field main_data"><input type="number" name="items['+ (int) +'][inv_quantity]" class="form-control quantity"  style="width: 70px"></td>'+ '<td><select name="items['+ (int) +'][inv_item]" class="form-control item" style="width: 250px"><option>Items</option></select></td>'+'<td><input type="text" name="items['+ (int) +'][inv_desc]" class="form-control description" style="width: 400px"></td>'+'<td><span class="tag tag-success"><input type="text" name="items['+ (int) +'][inv_price]" class="form-control u_price" style="width: 150px"></span></td>'+'<td><span class="tag tag-success"><input type="text" name="items['+ (int) +'][inv_tax]" class="form-control tax" style="width: 150px"></td>'+'<td><span class="tag tag-success"><input type="text" name="items['+ (int) +'][inv_total]" class="form-control amount" style="width: 150px"></td>'+'<td><span><button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="remove()"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></span><span><button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Row</button></span</td>'
   '</tr>';
   $('tbody').append(tr);
   int++;
}



function cal(){

    var qty= document.getElementById('qty_invoice').value;
    var unit = document.getElementById('price_invoice').value;
    var total = parseInt(qty*unit);
    document.getElementById('total').value = total;
    console.log(total);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-head-fixed text-nowrap" id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Qty</th>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Unit Price</th>
      <th>Tax</th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="main_data">
      <td><input type="number" name="items[0][inv_quantity]" class="form-control quantity" onkeyup="cal()" id="qty_invoice" style="width: 70px"></td>
      <td>
        <select name="items[0][inv_item]" class="form-control item" style="width: 250px">
          <option>Items</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="items[0][inv_desc]" class="form-control description" style="width: 400px"></td>
      <td><span class="tag tag-success"><input type="text" name="items[0][inv_price]" class="form-control u_price" onkeyup="cal()" id="price_invoice" style="width: 150px"></span></td>
      <td><span class="tag tag-success"><input type="text" name="items[0][inv_tax]" class="form-control tax" style="width: 150px"></td>
      <td><span class="tag tag-success"><input type="text" name="items[0][inv_total]" id="total" class="form-control amount" style="width: 150px"></td>
      <td>
        <span><button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="remove()"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></span>
        <span><button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Row</button></span>
      </td>

    </tr>


  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution and some comments:

1. You can use the `getElementsByName()` or the `getElementsByClass()` to have a collection of elements, iterate through them and calculate the sum.
2. The ids of the elements should be unique: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp

> The HTML id attribute is used to specify a unique id for an HTML element.
>
> You cannot have more than one element with the same id in an HTML document.

So the solution with the `getElementById` can't work.

3. To make this work, I'd suggest to have a dynamic id with an int appended and use the get by id function until you can't find any more items.
4. Check info about the name element: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_name.asp

It can be duplicated if you won't post this as a form.